# how to handle input arguments that may be one value or a list of many?

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I am working with a script from GitHub that someone wrote, which is designed for the command line. All the examples show something like:

```
thisscript.py -u 'teepee' -p pword999 -d 8
```

I want to run this inside another function, where I can use it like:

```
thisscript(username='teepee', password='pword999',...)
```

The main file includes a number of `class` definitions and this main function (below). What is the proper way to wrap this function such that I can call it as its own function?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...', add_help=False, usage='thisscript.py -u username -p password [options]')
    parser.add_argument('-u', metavar='<STR>', type=str, help='username')
    parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='<STR>', type=str, help='password')
    parser.add_argument('-a', metavar='<INT>', type=int, default=4, help='Number ascending [4]')
    parser.add_argument('-d', metavar='<INT>', type=int, default=0, help='Number descending [0]')
```

I have tried doing `import thisscript` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: from thisscript import main

Comment: The `__main__` block is not imported.  Show us the rest of the block, the part that does `args=parse_args()` and then does something with `args`.  What you show us just sets up the `parser`, it doesn't run or use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to call the script the way it was designed to be called -- in the shell -- by using the `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess

def transcript(
        username, 
        password, 
        descending_num=0, 
        ascending_num=4,
        ):

    command = f'transcript.py -u {username} -p {password} -d {descending_num} -a {ascending_num}'
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Giving the function keyword arguments to mirror the script's default arguments is optional, but makes usage clearer.